# Rename folder by removing characters in bracket

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

In an directory i have multiple subdirectories but some of them have square bracket in them and some characters in it. example

```
c:/folder/[Hello]folder1
c:/folder/fol[Hi]der2
c:/folder/[World]  Folder3
```

The output I want is as below

```
c:/folder/folder1
c:/folder/folder2
c:/folder/Folder3
```

I have tried something as below but couldn't fix it.

```
for /d %%i in (*.*) do for /f "delims=][" %%j in ("%%~i") do if "%%~i" neq "%%~j" echo ren "%%~i" "%%~j"
```

and

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%D IN ("*[*]*") do (
  SET name=%%~nxD
  echo "%%D"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerShell's `Rename-Item` cmdlet with the `-replace` regex operator to do this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\folder |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '\s*\[[^\[\]]+\]\s*'}
```

This will remove bracket pairs and their contents, as well as any whitespace surrounding them.

You can add the `-WhatIf` switch to verify the resulting names before executing:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\folder |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '\s*\[[^\[\]]+\]\s*'} -WhatIf
```